# Spring 5 + WebFlux Security + JWT tokens

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux, project-reactor

In a project where we use **Spring Boot 2 starters + Spring 5.0.7 + Reactor (WebFlux)**, we'd like to implement security using Spring Security. Just including the starter:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And the bean:

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().build();
    }
```

is more than enough.

However, we'd like to use JWT tokens (generated in another party, in a resource server) to intercept those `Authorization` headers. I've been struggling with this and I couldn't find any example for *Spring 5* (whereas for Spring <5 there are many examples and tutorials).

Has anybody bumped across this problem?

Comment: You can check https://medium.com/@ard333/authentication-and-authorization-using-jwt-on-spring-webflux-29b81f813e78.
The main idea is to install additional two beans into your springWebFilterChain: securityContextRepository and authenticationManager.
SecurityContextRepository is the main place for handling your JWT (parsing, verifying...) and AuthenticationManager is just a simple check to mark the request as authenticated, at least I can see like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On August 29th a new Spring version was released: 5.1. This version fixes this problem. The commit implements this is [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/bc6e4e6e55dff742868ab51eac92727e8e9dbb5f). The example of how to use it can be checked [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver-webflux/src/main/java/sample/SecurityConfig.java).

Comment: I made a demo project with a full JWT implementation using only jjwt lib, it is in  https://github.com/eriknyk/webflux-jwt-security-demo